# Why isn't my Unity rotation angle comparision not working?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make a game with movement. I'm trying to write an if-statement that checks if `transform.rotation.x` is greater than a value. However, currently there is no effect. I've tried changing the comparision operator to `>`, but it had no effect. This is  the code that I am using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public float moveSpeed;

    public Transform REVOLVR;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if(REVOLVR.rotation.x > -60)
        {
            this.transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * moveSpeed);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [`Transform.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) instead accessing the rotation quaternion's X-component individually. You also probably want to change the check to the domain [0, 360] as I believe that the euler angles are clamped to that domain.

Comment: thx. it worked.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Don't forget to accept the answer so that others can find help more easily in the future.